# isolate can't show local notifications and flutterisolate does not persiste after app killed

Tags: flutter

Ok. so i've written an isolate to show notifications more than once every 15 minutes.

If i use FlutterIsolate the isolate does not continue to persist after the app is killed.

If i use the method: Isolate, i get the following error message on showing a flutter_local_notification:

error: native function 'Window_sendPlatformMessage' (4 arguments) cannot be found

I've tried using sendport and receive port to keep the notifications running from within the ui thread. The code i've tried is below.  I'm using the latest flutter_local_notificaion paackage and have tried flutter-dev.

```
Isolate isolate = await Isolate.spawn(isolated, 'args' );
```

produces the afformentioned error.

```
FlutterIsolate isolate = await FlutterIsolate.spawn(isolated, 'args' );
```

does not persist.

I would like to show local notifications as part of an isolate. Any way out of this predicament?

Comment: Could yo post detail code? because I have tested with timer example. FlutterIsolate can work more than 15 minutes

Comment: Hi chunhunghan. It workswhen using flutterisolate but when i use that and kill the application it also kills the isolate, any idea on how to make the isolate persist?

Comment: Ok. whilst running the isolate within the ui thread works the isolate gets killed when the application is terminated. Running it from main produces an exception, but makes it persist after the applciation has been killed.  Going  to try passing the class as an object to the isolate now.

Comment: Merged each widget into the main class. now working (woop)